# Is `git rebase master` always followed by `git pull --rebase` and then `git push --force`?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I rebased my-branch over master:

`my-branch>> git rebase origin/master`

Then I see the status:

```
➜  supporTool git:(my-branch) git status
On branch my-branch
Your branch and 'origin/my-branch' have diverged,
and have 12 and 11 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

I understand the commits order have changed locally vs. remote (my-branch)

so does this mean I always have to do `git pull --rebase` and then `git push --force` to make the remote with the same commits order?

1) why do i need to pull if I'm the only developer on this branch and I was ahead of the remote, before rebasing on master?

2) what happens if someone else pushed something to the remote after I did the rebase locally but before pushing with `git push --force` ?

Comment: You can just use `git push --force-with-lease`. It will update the remote, unless someone else has pushed something else to the branch.

Comment: i want to understand the logic. what should i do if `someone else has pushed something else to the branch`

Comment: say no one has pushed something else to the branch, why should i rebase local on remote? wouldn't this lead to duplications?

Comment: Well, you rebase a branch on master to make sure your branch commits appear after the commits on master, and don't conflict with them. Merging on master is then a simple fast-forward.

Comment: @JBNizet  
what should i do if `someone else has pushed something else to the my-branch`? `git push --force-with-lease` will not help then

Comment: You would use git pull to merge (or rebase if you prefer) your local commits with the remote commits, and then use git push --force-with-lease again.

Comment: but the git pull will be messy because the local has changes atop of master commits. The remote and local will have lots of merge conflicts

Comment: Yes indeed. That's why rebasing a branch which are update by more than one people is not a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the commits' *order* that have changed.  It's the *commits themselves* that have changed.

To really understand all of this, you need to know three things:

- Branch *names* just point to commits.  Specifically, any one branch name, like `my-branch`, points to a *single* commit, which Git calls "the tip of the branch" or the *tip commit*.
- Branches—what we humans think of as branches, that is—are *chains* of commits.  This chaining is achieved internally through backwards arrows: each commit points backwards to a previous commit.  Collect up a chain of commits, with these internal backwards arrows, and you get a branch *tip*, pointed to by a branch *name*, that contains a series of commits:

  ```
  ...<- o <- o <- o <- o <- o    <-- branch1
              \
               o <- o <- o <-o   <-- branch2
  ```

  (The fact that the internal arrows are all backwards is usually not terribly important, so I tend to draw this instead as:

  ```
  o--o--o   <-- master
  ```

  which is a lot more readable.)
- The way `git rebase` works is that it *copies* commits.  Once it's done copying commits, it changes one (and only one!) branch *name* to point to the new, tip-most commit.

For instance, let's say the starting condition looks like this:

```
...--o--A--B            <-- master, origin/master
         \
          C--D--E--F    <-- my-branch, origin/my-branch
```

Here we have, in your repository, `master` (a regular ordinary local branch name) pointing to commit `B`—I've given them all one-letter names here, which are more [wieldy](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/wieldy) than 40-character-long hashes—and `origin/master` (a so-called *remote-tracking branch* name).  The remote-tracking branch name `origin/master` also points to commit `B`.

Commits `C` through `F` are on your branch `my-branch`, but not on branch `master`.  (This gives you 4 such commits, vs the 11 shown in your `git status`, so this drawing is simplified.)  Your remote-tracking branch name `origin/my-branch` also points to commit `F`.

But then you ran `git rebase master`.  This *copies* every commit that it needs to copy—which in this case is all of `C`, `D`, `E`, and `F`.  Git *gets* this list by enumerating all the commits that *are* on your current branch `my-branch`, that are *not* on branch `master`.  Note that *both* branches contain commit `A`, and any earlier commits, so these are the commits reachable from `my-branch` that `git rebase` throws out of the list.  This *reachability* idea depends on those backwards-pointing arrows; this is where the fact that the arrows point backwards actually matters.

So, let's see what happens if and when `git rebase` successfully copies those commits.  We get:

```
...--o--A--B              <-- master, origin/master
         \  \
          \  C'-D'-E'-F'  <-- my-branch
           \
            C--D--E--F    <-- origin/my-branch
```

The difference between commit `C`, the original, and commit `C'`, the copy, is that `C'` is built atop `B`.  It has whatever is different between `A` and `B`, plus the changes from `A` to `C`.<sup>1</sup>  Similarly, `D'` is built atop `C'`, and so on.

When the rebase finished, it moved *the current branch name* to point to the new tip-most commit, `F'`.  But it does not move any other name.  In particular, it does not move `origin/my-branch`—which makes a lot of sense, since `origin/my-branch` is meant to remember what *your* Git saw in `origin`'s Git for origin's `my-branch`, when your Git last talked with their Git via `git fetch` or `git push`.

Remember, all this action has taken place in *your* repository.  Presumably the repository over on `origin` is all unchanged.  This "presumably" *can* get us into trouble and that's where the "with lease" stuff comes in—but before we dive into that, take another look at the graph above.  Count how many commits are on `my-branch` and yet are not on `origin/my-branch`.  Then, count how many commits are on `origin/my-branch` but not on `my-branch`.

Remember, for this counting, we use *reachability*: we follow the internal arrows backwards.  Commit `A` is the first one on *both* branches.  The updated `my-branch` includes `A--B--C'-D'-E'-F'`: it has `A`.  The old `origin/my-branch` includes `A-C-D-E-F`: it has `A` too.  So we stop counting upon hitting `A`, and that means that `my-branch` now has five (not four!) commits that `origin/my-branch` lacks, while `origin/my-branch` has four commits that `my-branch` lacks.  (Compare this to your `git status`: you started with 11 commits on `my-branch` that were not also on `master`, and gained 1 more the same way, so you have 12-vs-11.)

All of the remaining commits on `origin/my-branch` are, of course, the ones we copied when rebasing.  The extra one on `my-branch` is just the one we picked up that's also on `master`: commit `B`.

---

<sup>1</sup>If the changes from `A` to `C` end up *replacing*, rather than augmenting, the changes from `A` to `B`, then the *tree* associated with `C'` matches the tree for `C`.  However, the parent ID remains different: `C`'s parent is `A`, while `C'`'s parent is `B`.  This alone suffices to make the two commits different: they will have a different 40-character SHA-1 hash.

---

## Pushing, with or without force and maybe lease

It's at this point, while you have this new graph, that you have decided to `git push` to get some or all of your new commits copied into the repository on `origin`.

The most fundamental bit of `git push`—the part it always does—consists of contacting another Git, via some URL, and taking some of your commit(s) and handing them over to that other Git.  The URL normally comes from the remote name, `origin`.  A remote is, to a first approximation, just a short name for the full URL.  So the remaining interesting part, in fact the more-interesting part, is this handing-over process.

To hand over some commit(s), you tell your Git to find specific *tip* commits, usually by giving your Git a branch name like `my-branch`.  To tell your Git what to tell the *other* Git, you also give your Git another branch name.  You separate these two branch names with a colon, as in:

```
git push origin my-branch:my-branch
```

The name on the left is how you tell your Git which *tip* commit to push.  The name on the right is how you tell your Git which branch you'd like *their* Git to change on *their* end.

Usually, of course, these are the same, so your Git lets you leave out the repetitive repeating repetition of repeating `:my-branch`.  (This sentence is brought to you by the Department of Redundancy Department.)  So you just run:

```
git push origin my-branch
```

or, with a modern (2.0 or later) version of Git,<sup>2</sup> the even-simpler:

```
git push
```

(this figures out the right stuff from your current branch's *upstream* setting).  But it's important to keep in mind that this "means" `git push origin my-branch:my-branch`, i.e., use *your* `my-branch` to find the tip commit, have *your* Git hand *their* Git that commit, and have your Git ask *their* Git to set *their* `my-branch`.  (This is how and why it's possible to use different branch *names* in your repository vs their repository—not something you'll need often, but when you *do* want it, it turns out to be extremely handy.)

When your Git contacts their Git, your Git starts by handing over these tip commit IDs.  (You can push more than one branch at a time, hence "tip IDs" is plural.)  Their Git then checks to see if they already have the commits—by their unique, 40-character hash IDs—and if not, has your Git send over the actual contents of the commit, including the commits' parent IDs.  Their Git asks for more object contents as needed.  This conversation goes on until your Git has given their Git something they recognize: a hash ID they already have, such as commit `B` in our drawing.

At this point, your Git has handed over all the commits you must give them (plus any additional internal Git objects—trees and blobs—all of which have their own unique hash IDs), and now their Git begins the evaluation process.

---

<sup>2</sup>The key item here is the configuration setting of `push.default`, which in Git 2.0-and-later is `simple`, if you don't change it.  In earlier versions of Git it was set to `matching` by default.

---

#### To force, or not to force

Git is built around the idea of *adding new stuff*.

Specifically, whenever you make a new commit, you simply *add it on* to the existing commit chain.  Whatever branch you're on now, you add one new commit and move the branch label forward to accommodate it:

```
before:
...--C--D--E   <-- my-branch

after:
...--C--D--E--F   <-- my-branch
```

Git therefore *expects* branch labels to move like this: to add new commits.

So, for a normal `git push`, without `--force`, Git will allow the push if the result *only adds new commits*.  It doesn't matter how complex the push is:

```
before:
...--o--o--o    <-- branch

after:       o-------o
            /         \
...--o--o--o--o--o--o--o---o   <-- branch
               \          /
                o--o--o--o
```

the key question is: does it only *add*, or does it *drop* something?  The above is allowed, but the below is not:

```
before:
...--o--o--o--o    <-- branch

after:
...--o--o--x--x
         \
          o--o    <-- branch
```

A branch label only points to *one* commit, so if Git were to allow this push, the last two commits on the top row (now marked `x--x`) would be "forgotten".

So now, look back at your rebase graphs.  If you push the new `my-branch`, all the *original* commits—the ones you copied so as to put them after the tip of `master`—would be "forgotten".

Of course, this is precisely what you want.  You are abandoning the originals in favor of the new copies.  You want `origin` to abandon them as well.

This is where `--force` comes in: a `git push --force` sets the "force flag", which your Git passes along to the other Git.  Their Git need not *obey* the force flag at all, but if they do, it simply tells them: "yeah, go ahead and forget some commits."

#### The force flag is *too* powerful

Now, *as long as the upstream `origin` Git repository hasn't actually changed here,* using `--force` or its equivalent works fine.  You copied your `C-D-E-F` commit chain and you're pushing the copies, so if they "forget" the original `C-D-E-F`, that's just fine.

If `my-branch` really *is* private to you, we're done.  We don't need to worry about other possibilities.  But what if it's not?  What if someone *else* might have said "oh, wow, branch `my-branch` has great stuff, let me just add commit `G` and push" and they did that and the Git over on `origin` now has the chain `C-D-E-F-G`:

```
...--o--A--B                <-- master
         \  \
          \  C'-D'-E'-F'    [proposed replacement]
           \
            C--D--E--F--G   <-- my-branch
```

Note the lack of `origin/` here: this is a drawing of the repository *on* `origin`; so it does not have `origin/` in its own names.  That's also why `F'` is the tip of the proposed replacement for `my-branch`.

If their Git takes the proposed replacement, their Git will lose commit `G`.  *You* don't have commit `G`, so you did not copy it to a new `G'`.

#### Force with lease

The idea behind the `--force-with-lease` option is actually taken from multiprocessing computers' "compare and swap" or CAS instructions, and internally, it's actually called the "cas" option.  The way it works is that your Git tells their Git: "I *believe* your `my-branch` points to commit `F`, and I'd like you to forcibly change it to `F'`."

If, in fact, their Git's `my-branch` *does* point to `F`, the `--force-with-lease` push succeeds, replacing their `my-branch` so that it now points to the `F'` you gave them.

If, on the other hand, their Git's `my-branch` got updated, the `--force-with-lease` push fails.  You can now run `git fetch` to bring over any new commits and find out where their `my-branch` label actually *does* point.  Note that your Git gets its notion of where "their" branch points ("I believe your `my-branch` is...") from *your* `origin/my-branch`.  There are force-with-lease variants that let you control this more finely, but you are unlikely to need them.

That is *all* it does: it just modifies the strong "force" into a slightly weaker "force, but only if ...".  If you are trying to coöperate with someone else, though, working on a branch that gets rebased or rewritten like this and pushed through some central server, "force with lease" can be quite helpful.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to write in details explaining what happens after rebase. I did a simple test, say, I have my-branch with one commit "A" after branching off from master, someone commits "B" to master, I want to get "B" to my-branch, I do "git rebase master", in SourceTree, my-branch shows 1 pull and 2 pushes which is exactly as torek says, it becomes --B--A' (2 pushes) in my local branch, while still --A (1 pull) in origin:my-branch. Next I need to do "push -- force" to tell origin:my-branch to make the change same as my-branch in local, forget --A.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the basic rule: *always pull before rebase.*

Before you rebase your work on top of the integration branch (whether it's `master` or `develop`), you need to make sure you have the latest commits that people have put on the integration branch. So here's what you should do:

1. Save your work. Commit everything you want to save in your feature branch (`my-branch`) and make sure `git status` reports no uncommitted changes.
2. Check out the integration branch (`git checkout master`, for example) and `git pull` to get the latest. At this point your local branch `master` is exactly the same as your remote tracking branch `origin/master`.
3. Check out your feature branch (shortcut: `git checkout -` to 'jump back to the previous branch').
4. Rebase: `git rebase master` to put your feature branch on top of the latest `master` commit.
5. Publish: `git push -u --force-with-lease origin my-branch:my-branch` (first time, to set up tracking properly for your feature branch) and `git push --force-with-lease` (every other time).

This series of steps will ensure your feature branches are always cleanly on top of `master` and are easy to merge when the time comes.

Answer (score 1):

git rebase is not intended to be used in public branch (master or develop branch if you follow feature or hot-fix workflow)

1. Because rebasing changes history
2. Where will you exactly rebase?