# git pull and rebase from develop

Tags: git, rebase

If I have local develop branch, tracked with origin/develop. I work on my feature in a local branch. I then switch back to develop and there have been other remote commits that I need to integrate.

Can I safely pull from origin/develop with a rebase instead of merge? Will this cause any problems with the other developers branch history?

Comment: "I then switch back to develop..." You mean you just checked out *develop*? You didn't merge your feature branch back to it yet?        "...and there have been other changes." You mean additional commits have been pushed to the *develop* branch on _origin_?

Comment: @JamieBisotti Yes. I switch back to develop branch as I'm planning to merge my feature into it. Yes, there have been additional commits. So I want to pull these first, then merge my feature in. So I want to rebase first, and then merge my feature in. I'm asking if the rebase is fine to do

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/40208194/20371

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is \`git rebase master\` always followed by \`git pull --rebase\` and then \`git push --force\`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40203410/is-git-rebase-master-always-followed-by-git-pull-rebase-and-then-git-push)

Answer (score 0):

Then I would...

```
# Get the latest from the remote
git fetch

# Bring your local develop up to date
git checkout develop
git rebase origin/develop

# Put your feature atop the latest commits
git checkout feature
git rebase origin/develop

# Merge your feature back to develop
git checkout develop
git merge --no-ff feature

git push origin develop
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I've gathered from you question and your comments, I don't think you even need to rebase. So long as you haven't done any local work on your `develop` branch, you should just be able to do:

```
git checkout develop
git pull origin develop
```

From there, you can then merge your `feature` branch into `develop` with `git merge feature` from your `develop` branch.