# getting remote changes on my local copy

Tags: git

this is probably very trivial but I am confused by terminology used in git.

I have a local branch with lots of uncommited and modified files, and there is a remote/master branch.

I am not ready to push all my local changes to remote/branch since it would start a large merge. I would just like to receive the other changes in remote/branch and apply them on my local version without changing branch.

how to do this?
I have been using git extensions but it is not available for me now, I only can use git CLI

Comment: Have you tried `git pull`?  What did it say?

Comment: so if I do `git pull remote master` it should not delete my precious local changes?

Comment: I am not keen on experimenting because an error here can cost me really a lot

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40208194/20371 for a way to do this safely. If there are merge conflicts you will, of course, need to resolve them. It's important to learn how to do that also.

Answer (score 2):

You must use `git pull` to achieve what you want.

See this comment: [What is the difference between 'git pull' and 'git fetch'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/what-is-the-difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch#comment3045424_292359)

And, of course, for real learning, Git documentation: [git pull](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull)

Comment: I have done my learning. I would have had to stash the changes

Comment: However the automerge after `git stash apply` changed some files so now I have to go through them one by one and remove the <<< change upstream part

Comment: exactly what I wanted to avoid, what was the right way to avoid this?

Comment: @Liborio: The way to avoid this is never to "have a local branch with lots of uncommited and modified files."  Commit and merge earlier and more often.

Answer (score 1):

First what you need to do is make sure your master is latest and greatest. If not just do `git pull origin master`.

Secondly then commit your local changes to your branch and merge that branch into your master and then push your master to the origin.